# How can I loop over the @pytest.mark.parametrize data or print it on the tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I have this data that basically are parameters that i want to pass into a function:

```
data2 = { "user": "bender", "resource": "machine/2", "action": "delete"}
data3 = { "user": "bender", "resource": "machine/2", "action": "delete"}
data4 = { "user": "bender", "resource": "machines/*", "action": "*"}
data5 = { "user": "leela", "resource": "machine/1", "action": "delete"}
data6 = { "user": "leela", "resource": "machine/*", "action": "*"}
```

I have this test using `@pytest.mark.parametrize` :

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input",  [
    data2,
    data3,
    data4,
    data5,
    data6,
])
@patch("dev_maintenance.roles.db")
def test_check_if_user_has_permissions(db,test_input):
    tmp = {}
    tmp["user"] = "bender"
    tmp["resource"] = "machine/1"
    tmp["action"] = "delete"

    db.session.query.return_value.filter_by.return_value.join.return_value.all.return_value = [(tmp["user"], tmp["resource"], tmp["action"])]

    assert check_if_user_has_permissions(user = "bender",resource= "machine/1", access_token= "delete") == True
```

What I want to achieve is pass each data set on the `check_if_user_has_permissions(user, resource, action)` so I can assert is value, and if the assert fails because the assertion was `True == False` I want that test case to pass, because in my scenario if this happens it means that the user has no permissions, and the test should pass.

I was trying to print on the tests like `print(test_input)` to see if it would print all data sets but in only prints one.

Comment: It seems like you're asking two separate questions.  If you want to assert a negative just use `assert not`.  If you run pytest with the `-v` flag it will output all the tests it's running, and for parametrized tests it will also show each parameter value it's running the test with.

Comment: It also looks like you're not actually using `test_input` in your test implementation.

Comment: You can use ‘-s‘ in the end of your command line call. It will print to console whatever you will pass to print method. Example: py.test -v -s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're asking two separate questions. If you want to assert a negative just use `assert not`. If you run pytest with the `-v` flag it will output all the tests it's running, and for parametrized tests it will also show each parameter value it's running the test with.

You can write your test sort of like this:

```
$ cat test.py
import pytest

data = [
    { "user": "bender", "resource": "machine/2", "action": "delete"},
    { "user": "bender", "resource": "machine/2", "action": "delete"},
    { "user": "bender", "resource": "machines/*", "action": "*"},
    { "user": "leela", "resource": "machine/1", "action": "delete"},
    { "user": "leela", "resource": "machine/*", "action": "*"}
]


def check_if_user_has_permissions(*args, **kwargs):
    # Dummy implementation for demonstration
    import random
    print(kwargs)
    return random.choice([True, False])


@pytest.mark.parametrize('test_input', data)
def test_check_if_user_has_permissions(test_input):
    # ... additional test setup ...
    assert not check_if_user_has_permissions(**test_input)
```

Then run:

```
$ pytest -v test.py
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform cygwin -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-5.3.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: .
collected 5 items

test.py::test_check_if_user_has_permissions[test_input0] PASSED          [ 20%]
test.py::test_check_if_user_has_permissions[test_input1] PASSED          [ 40%]
test.py::test_check_if_user_has_permissions[test_input2] PASSED          [ 60%]
test.py::test_check_if_user_has_permissions[test_input3] FAILED          [ 80%]
test.py::test_check_if_user_has_permissions[test_input4] FAILED          [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
_______________ test_check_if_user_has_permissions[test_input3] ________________

test_input = {'action': 'delete', 'resource': 'machine/1', 'user': 'leela'}

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('test_input', data)
    def test_check_if_user_has_permissions(test_input):
>       assert not check_if_user_has_permissions(**test_input)
E       AssertionError: assert not True
E        +  where True = check_if_user_has_permissions(**{'action': 'delete', 'resource': 'machine/1', 'user': 'leela'})

test.py:21: AssertionError
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
{'user': 'leela', 'resource': 'machine/1', 'action': 'delete'}
_______________ test_check_if_user_has_permissions[test_input4] ________________

test_input = {'action': '*', 'resource': 'machine/*', 'user': 'leela'}

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('test_input', data)
    def test_check_if_user_has_permissions(test_input):
>       assert not check_if_user_has_permissions(**test_input)
E       AssertionError: assert not True
E        +  where True = check_if_user_has_permissions(**{'action': '*', 'resource': 'machine/*', 'user': 'leela'})

test.py:21: AssertionError
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
{'user': 'leela', 'resource': 'machine/*', 'action': '*'}
========================= 2 failed, 3 passed in 0.19s ==========================
```

Comment: Print(kwargs) will not print anything in console until you use -s while running test. Example: pytest -v -s test.py

Comment: It will if the test fails.  It depends on whether or not you *always* want to print it, or just in cases that fail.  I would recommend the latter.  Lots of output from passing tests tends to be noise.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier solution to this problem after some time.

I did a `mark.parametrize` like this:

```
data = 
[
["bender", "machine_4", "action1", False],
["leela", "machine_2", "action1", False],
["leela", "file/2", "action4", True],
["leela", "file/2", "action2", False],
["leela", "application/1", "action1", True],
["leela", "application/2", "action1", False],
["fry", "application/1", "action1", True],
["zoidberg", "application/1", "action1", False],
]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("user,resource,action, expected", data)
@patch("dev_maintenance.roles.db")
def test_check_if_user_has_permissions(db,user,resource,action,expected):

    db.session.query.return_value.filter_by.return_value.join.return_value.all.return_value = \
        [
            ("bender", "machine_1", "action1"),
            ("bender", "machine_2", "action1"),
            ("bender", "machine_3", "action1"),
            ("bender", "machine_3", "action2"),
            ("leela", "file/*", "action4"),
            ("leela", "application/1", "*"),
            ("fry", "*", "*"),
        ]

    assert check_if_user_has_permissions(user, resource, action) == expected
```

What i did here was passing the `user`, `resource` and `action` parameters to the function and assert that the response of the function with those parameters is equal to the `expected` parameter.
So it will work like True == True, depending on the parameters.